# Unity - Errors after computer crashs

Tags: unity-game-engine

I was working on my unity project until the computer showed a blue screen. After turning on the computer, I noticed that no information was displayed in the inspector, and an error was displayed in the console every frame:

P.S. I use joystick pack from unity asset store

```
TypeLoadException: Could not load type DynamicJoystick, Assembly-CSharp, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null while decoding custom attribute: (null)
System.MonoCustomAttrs.GetCustomAttributesBase (System.Reflection.ICustomAttributeProvider obj, System.Type attributeType, System.Boolean inheritedOnly) (at <feaaa6313e32495d9f259b175aa6b597>:0)
System.MonoCustomAttrs.GetCustomAttributes (System.Reflection.ICustomAttributeProvider obj, System.Type attributeType, System.Boolean inherit) (at <feaaa6313e32495d9f259b175aa6b597>:0)
System.RuntimeType.GetCustomAttributes (System.Type attributeType, System.Boolean inherit) (at <feaaa6313e32495d9f259b175aa6b597>:0)
UnityEditor.CustomEditorAttributes.Rebuild () (at <ed149e892fca4713a3001773d054b5ca>:0)
UnityEditor.CustomEditorAttributes.FindCustomEditorTypeByType (System.Type type, System.Boolean multiEdit) (at <ed149e892fca4713a3001773d054b5ca>:0)
UnityEditor.CustomEditorAttributes.FindCustomEditorType (UnityEngine.Object o, System.Boolean multiEdit) (at <ed149e892fca4713a3001773d054b5ca>:0)
UnityEditor.AssetPreviewUpdater.CreatePreview (UnityEngine.Object obj, UnityEngine.Object[] subAssets, System.String assetPath, System.Int32 width, System.Int32 height) (at <ed149e892fca4713a3001773d054b5ca>:0)
UnityEditor.AssetPreviewUpdater.CreatePreviewForAsset (UnityEngine.Object obj, UnityEngine.Object[] subAssets, System.String assetPath) (at <ed149e892fca4713a3001773d054b5ca>:0)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)
```

Comment: You might want to try closing Unity, deleting your project’s Library folder and reloading to reimport everything. If there actually was a problem with the joystick pack you could always reimport that, but I don’t think it’s the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I just created a new project and moved the assets folder into it. It worked but had to re-import all the packages

Answer (score 0):

Just open any script make some changes (can be a comment like) and save the script. That will be ok. Then open another scene to solve script reference issue if you got.